# How to deploy code using codedeploy to multiple EC2 instances having different deploy paths

Tags: aws-code-deploy

How to deploy code to multiple EC2 instances which are having different deploy paths.
For example: I have 2 EC2 instances (WEB,APP) in DEV as well as SIT environments.

In webserver I have a deployment path like `D:/deployments/latest` and in app server I have a deployment path like `C:/inetpub/wwwroot`. How can I deploy code to these paths using appspec.yml file.Any ideas will be very helpful.

I have copied the code using appspec.yml file to `c:/codedeploydeployments` path in all the servers.Next step is I used afterinstall.bat to copy the files from `c:/codedeploydeployments` to `D:/deployments/latest` (web server) and `C:/inetpub/wwwroot(in appserver)`,but the deployment is failed.

```
if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "webserver" ]; then
  xcopy "c:/codedeploydeployments" "D:/deployments/latest" 
else
  # Fail the deployment
fi
```

First I wanted to test only for webserver .I have created an application with 2 deployment groups webserver and appserver and tagged web inastances to webser deployment group.

Please let me know if there is any error in the above afterinstall.bat

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Please see the following example which is a slight modification and should not result in a failed deployment. Although this example is for Linux, but can be used in Windows case with slight modification:

Appspec:-

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: files/html.txt
    destination: /tmp/files

  AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/RunDev.sh
    - location: Scripts/RunStage.sh
```

RunDev.sh :-

```
if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Dev" ]
then
     mv /tmp/files/* /home/Dev
fi
```

RunStage.sh :-

```
if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "Stage" ]
then
     mv /tmp/files/* /home/Stage
fi
```

Comment: @ shariqmaws,I tried the below.It is still throwing an error.                                                                              
 if [ "$DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME" == "webserver" ]; then
  xcopy "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testcodedeploy\" "D:\Myproject\test"
else
  # Fail the deployment
fi

Comment: I added a bat script to copy the files to multiple location.It is working as expected.